# My python function is supposed to work but it is not returning anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

So I've been trying to learn Python and after some easy codes (or whatever they are called) I am now trying to recreate a drinkinggame i always play with some friends. But for that i need this function to return a value which it doesn't do. Can anyone help me? (sorry for the bad English)

```
def throw():
        dice = 6
        List = []
        i = 0
        while i <= dice - len(List):
            i +=1
            List.append(random.randint(1,6))
        return List 

print(throw(List))
```

Comment: It's `print(throw())`, your function doesn't take any argument.

Comment: `List` is a reserved term in python I think.  Try changing your variable name. Also, in your print statement change it to `print(throw())`

Comment: @user1558604 `list` is, `List` isn't. The tradition, though, is to only use capitalized names for classes.

Comment: For your future questions, please always include the complete error traceback so that we don't have to guess what doesn't work or run the code.

Comment: The error message tells you very explicitly what's wrong. The variable `List` is not defined or accessible outside the `def`; nor should you be passing it to the `throw` function, which doesn't take any parameters. Demo: https://ideone.com/WGNbIm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your function isn't receiving any parameter, so don't pass anything.

```
import random 
def throw():
        dice = 6
        List = []
        i = 0
        while i <= dice - len(List):
            i +=1
            List.append(random.randint(1,6))
        return List 

print(throw()) # here
```